# Websphere null.ear error at runtime in WAS7

Tags: websphere, java-6

I am deploying an ear file in Websphere WAS7 console. The application is built on JDK1.6. The deployment is successful with no errors. But when I try to test the process by pushing a file, I am getting the below error during runtime.

```
E   CWPST0164E: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv1/config/cells/lvqma942Cell/applications/null.ear/deployments/deployment.xml composition unit is not found.
```

Has anyone came across this? I can post more info as needed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sanity check - your application isn't actually named "null", is it?  If not, then it looks like deployment wasn't really successful, because you apparently have an app with a null name in your config.

Comment: There is no application named "null". Deployment didn't give any error. i also checked the path /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv1/config/cells/lvqma942Cell/applications and dont see null.ear file in there.

Comment: UPDATE: On further research, we found that this is occurring in production as well with no issues to the business flow. So apparently its something to do with the websphere config which is also shared by other applications. (Thought it will help a few)!